# jasmine 2.0 async assignin variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I want to set 2 variables to my test case which an async function returns. In a prior attempt I was using runs() and waitsFor() but I want to use jasmine 2.0's done() functionality. I tried something like this:

```
describe("Test", function() {

    it("makes a log file", function(done) {
        make_valid_detailed(1, 2, '2014-02-20', 'test.txt', location, function(error, returnCode, path) {
            this.lpath = path;
            this.status_code = returnCode;
        });
        expect(this.lpath).toBeDefined();
        expect(this.status_code).toBeDefined();
        done();
    });

});
```

I'd like the variables to be accessible to ever subsequent test, it() scenario.  I always et 'undefined' as it stands now.  Ultimately I will have a few async functions run that set some variables, and then the rest of the tests test what those variables are, files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring javascript basic scoping rules, this changes according to the function context.Furthermore,if make_valid_detailed is async,your 2 variables will not be defined since the 2 expect functions will execute before it.

```
describe("Test", function() {

it("makes a log file", function(done) {
    make_valid_detailed(1, 2, '2014-02-20', 'test.txt', location, function(error, returnCode, path) {
       expect(path).toBeDefined();
       expect(returnCode).toBeDefined();
       done();
    });


});

});
```

Comment: With the runs() and waitsFor() syntax it was clear what to wait for.  I'm confused how to achieve this with only the done() syntax. I am new to JS and Jasmine if you can't tell :)

Comment: That actually works fine for running the async test. But how do you then set a variable ouside of it().  I want to set path so that all it() can use the var path.